# create a doskey like ~ in unix

Tags: windows, unix, terminal, cmd.exe

I'm writing a small little BAT file that has the ability to create doskey's (alias) like those in Unix. for example:

```
doskey cat=type $*
doskey ..=cd..
```

I just want these BAT files so I can put them on a flashdrive and run then when I need to work on a Windows machine (I primary use linux/Macintosh computers)

How would i write this:

```
doskey ~= "code here"
```

I want it to work so that if I am the current user 'username'
it will take me directly to the directory of 'C:/Users/username'

when i type:

```
cd ~
```

any ideas?

I tried this but it didn't work

```
doskey ~=echo C:/Users/%username% | cd
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `~` emulation, use `cd /d "%USERPROFILE%"`

For other possibly useful variables, type `set` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the cmd/dos prompt.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! thanks just so used to unix it's hard to work with Windows!

Comment: The console server, conhost.exe, matches aliases starting at the beginning of a line of input. You can use `doskey cd~=cd /d ^%USERPROFILE^%`. It can't match a space in the source, so I used `cd~` with no space. You'd add this in C as follows: `AddConsoleAliasW(L"cd~", L"cd /d %USERPROFILE%", L"cmd.exe")`.

Answer (score 0):

to create a simple doskey `doskey explorer=start .` *this will open the directory in explorer*

And I will try to make your idea
`doskey cd~=cd C:\Users\%username%`
It didn't work as you wanted because I coudn't put a space, but if you type `cd~` it will do the same thing

for more doskey macros visit [my garbage repo](https://github.com/garbageoverflow/cmd-macros)